# Symfony2 render page and redirect to those page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, redirect

I'm just trying to make a simple trick, but can't find a solution. I'm sending a post request from angular.js app, using $http method. Everything I want it's to be redirected to twig template, where post data will be parsed. I was trying `$this->redirect, $this->render`, or

```
   /**
     * @Route("/print/quote")
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function printQuoteAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('printQuotAction', array(
            'data' => $request->request->all()
        )));
    }
```

but this not working for me, what can I do?

Also, I was trying to

```
        return $this->render('PTHearingBundle:Print:quote.html.twig', array(
            'data' => $request->request->all()
        ));
```

And its really renders a page, but returning html markup as response, but I want to be redirected to this page.

Comment: What do you mean with: " I want to be forced to those page" ?

Comment: To be redirected automatically

Comment: Ok. I know nothing about angular.js, but I guess it is sending and XHR request, so it cannot be redirected. You should get the return value and do the redirect from the angular.js side

Comment: Looks like that, but I need to pass a lot of data to this template that's why I cant use get request query string. Is there any another options?

Comment: Couldn't you just render the page from symfony and then put the resulting HTML somewhere in your page via sngular.js? I used to do something similar directiy with `JQuery`

Comment: Not really, the problem is that I'm trying to render a new page that extends from own index.html.twig file, so I can't use this. But your answer was very helpful and I have found a solution because of it. I'm just doing a redirect to page like print/1/12, where 1, 12 id of database objects. Then, I'm getting this data and return a render response. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the twig template via

```
$this->render
```

or

```
$this->redirect
```

do

```
return JsonResponse('redirectUrl' => $url, 'success' => true);
```

and inside the success function of your `$http.post/get` do

```
$location.path(url);
```

Basically you should just return the path to redirect in your `XHR` call and redirect via angular's `$location` module.